# Unity: Particle System turn invisible when turning camera away

Tags: unity, particles

When turning the camera away the particles disappear as seen: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9Z7RALEzCQ&feature=youtu.be).

I set the shape of the spawner to a custom mesh. I usually use Box as the shape of the Particle spawner and never had any problems with it.

Bounds:

[image]

Settings of Particle System:

[image]

Comment: Have you check if the gameobject holding the particule system is destroyed?
Maybe it is holding a script that destroy it after a condition or a certain time.

Comment: It sounds like the bounding box of your particle system isn't accurately reflecting the actual volume its particles can occupy, leading Unity to disable it with frustum culling when it thinks it's off-screen, before it's actually ready to be culled that way. What do you see when you tick "show bounds" in the little overlay that appears in your scene view when you have the particle system selected?

Comment: @DMGregory I figured it had something to do with the bounds. Thanks for pointing out the "show bounds" setting. The image is posted in the main answer. How do I fix the bounds?

Comment: Hmm... it looks like your bounds aren't taking into account the rotation of your mesh. I haven't been able to reproduce this in my own tests - as I rotate the mesh using the Shape module or the Transform, the bounds appear to update correctly. Are you able to walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example in a new empty project? Something to check: if your mesh is created in code, have you updated its bounds with `RecalculateBounds()`?

Comment: @DMGregory This seems to be a unity bug. By changing the rotation & position inside the "Shape" settings within the particle FX it does not affect the bounds. (I don't know how to recalculate bounds on the mesh inside the particle FX) I rotated the Particle using the main Transform at the top of the inspeector and it works now. See how i change the rotation and position here: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/5e8c80-1592728496.jpg  AND HERE:  https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/29050e-1592728503.jpg Definitely a bug!

Comment: I have actually rotated it inside blender... But using normal transform would have certainly worked also. X-90 and scale to x100 is standard conversion from blender to unity. In Blender 1 unit is seen as 1cm and Z axis is up. You can change it in the export settings I believe but it's too late for that now...